# Hide "Home" menu wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes

i want hide "home" in my menu when the people visit my page on mobile. When people connect from desktop or laptop i don't want hide "home". I use bridge theme. it's possible do it?

thank your for the attention, and excuse for my bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css media query and hide in mobile by menu item ID
Example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  #menu-item-98 {
    display:none;
  }
}
```